# is it a good practice to send id parameter of a table row to the client

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have  entity objects Genre and Songs, and relationship between them one to many, anyways in order to add a song to a particular genre i need to get the id of the given genre, what i'm doing is when the list of genres renders i give my addbutton which generates for each of my genre a property of name equal to the genre id.. I would like to know if this technique is acceptable and proper, to uncover such properties like id to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is and isn't acceptable as there are serious security implications of this. I have an attribute I use for this. Im on the phone here but will update this post later. Check out Dev333 tech Ed talk video on channel 9 near the end for parameter tampering as well I demo te attribute there. Ideally you want to encrypt it to prevent tampering if possible.